# Including a modal anchor tag in an ASP.NET MVC Html.ActionLink

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html-helper, actionlink

How do I insert a modal anchor `#modal1` in this actionLink?

```
   <td >@Html.ActionLink("Select", "order", "book", New With {.id = Item.id}, New With {.class = "btn btn-success"})</td>
```

I try to like this but it doesnt work

```
   <td >@Html.ActionLink("Select", "order", "book", New With {.id = Item.id}, New With {.class = "btn btn-success"})#modal1</td>
```

Comment: It doesnt work for me

Comment: Then you did not read and implement the dupe correctly!